# Как программно создать GridLayout

Tags: java, android

Нужно создать таблицу типа такой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как объединять ячейки в GridLayout программно, т.к. данные получаются с сайта?
Пробовал через table, но как я понял там нельзя объединять ячейки